# Excel: paste text into excel field and have it autopopulate the correct cells

Tags: excel, text, paste

Currently, I have text files that state a parameter and a value.  I would like to figure out how I could just paste the information in an excel field or cell than have it populate the correct cells with the values instead of manually doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on open a file in Excel and select all files in the dialog box that appears after that proceed with the selection of the text file. Supposing your text file has adjacent columns and they are separated by tabs or commas then select "Delimited" radio button, if they have fixed spacing then select the "Fixed width" radio button. Furthermore, you can also select from which line to import. Click next and you will be provided with a screen allowing you to select columns widths which is pretty self-explanatory. After this proceed to next step where you select the formatting of the column data(general, text, data). Setting for decimal and thousands separators are under the advanced tab. I have written this based on Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be accomplished with **Named Ranges**.  Once the worksheet is ready, assign a **Name** to the cells requiring value population.  Then VBA code could be written to read the text file and populate the values into the correct cells.